# Best way to turn down iOS users with legacy version of iOS

Tags: ios, mobile-application

I am building an iOS 8 app (iOS 7 and below not supported).

Is there a standard procedure to "turn down" a user with a legacy version of iOS? (E.g. Use a modal with some text, and then automatically shut down the app after 5 seconds.)

Comment: Doesn't the App Store let you specify the minimum version, which will prevent someone from even downloading it with an earlier one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple's docs on that, you can restrict it to iOS7 just by requiring a feature that needs iOS7. No needs to implement any special UX flow, since the store gives you ability to restrict the download to compatibile devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Comment: Thanks. So basically I can require `healthkit` or `metal`.

Comment: At times its best to drop support for older OS versions since it just doesn't make sense to continue to support it. You are in a lucky position since you don't already have a version of your app in the wild. If you did have a version of your app that has iOS6 users, and you wanted to drop support for them, you could still do it by updating minimum iOS version to say 7 and users on iOS 7 or above would only get the update.